# Could do with some help with a SQL join statement please

Tags: sql, join

Hi I usually hunt the net and sleep on things until I find the answer but the following seemingly simple problem is completely evading me.

I have 2 tables,

**TBL_Incidents**

```
IncidentID
IncidentDate
IncidentReportedBy
IncidentDescription
```

and **TBL_Comments**

```
CommentID
CommentFromUser
Comment
```

There are multiple comments per incident.

I'd like to get all information from TBL_Incidents where any of the incident's comments come from a particular user.

All the joins I've tried duplicate the incidents, including the left join that I was sure would have worked, e.g.

```
IncidentID | IncidentDate (+ all other TBL_Incident fields) | CommentID
4 | ... | 2
4 | ... | 3
4 | ... | 5
9 | ... | 12
9 | ... | 13
```

It's like I want to use a group by on the Incident ID, but then it won't give me the rest of the info from TBL_Incidents because they're not in the group by clause.

a) does anyone have any idea what I'm babbling on about?

b) does anyone know whether it's possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Wow thanks guys, yes indeed the Comments table has an IncidentID field, well spotted. I'll try out all your great suggestions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where Incidents and Comments are related.  Is there an IncidentID in TBL_Comments?  If so, then you would join on IncidentID and filter on CommentFromUser like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL_Incidents JOIN TBL_Comments ON TBL_Incidents.IncidentID = TBL_Comments.IncidentID
WHERE TBL_Comments.CommentFromUser = UserID
```

If there is no IncidentID in TBL_Comments then there is not enough information available to link them together...

Minor reading comprehension fail edit:

Assuming you've got the ID and you're just combatting duplicates, slap a DISTINCT on there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TBL_Incidents.*
    FROM TBL_Incidents JOIN TBL_Comments ON TBL_Incidents.IncidentID = TBL_Comments.IncidentID
    WHERE TBL_Comments.CommentFromUser = UserID
```

Comment: That's presumably what he's doing to produce the results he has.  As he indicates, this will produce multiple rows for a single incident if there is more than one comment from the given user.

Comment: Pete, you are a genius, the Distinct did the trick. I'd vote you up but as I've just registered I don't have the reputation to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: You could always "Accept" the answer.  ;o)

Comment: Thanks Pete <newb>Casualbob</newb>

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IndicentID, IncidentDate, IncidentReportedBy, IncidentDescription
FROM   TBL_Incidents I
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TBL_Comments C
               WHERE  C.IncidentID = I.IncidentID
               AND    C.CommentFromUser = 'YourUser')
```

This assumes that TBL_Comments has an IncidentID column, which if you are somehow able to do a join, it must (or have something similar).

Answer (score 1):

The table description that you showed above does not indicate how the tables are related... Based on the description, let's say TBL_Comments has a key to the parent table...

```
TBL_Incidents

IncidentID
IncidentDate
IncidentReportedBy
IncidentDescription

and TBL_Comments

CommentID
CommentFromUser
Comment
IncidentID -- parent key from TBL_Incidents.
```

YOur query would be...

```
select * from tbl_incidents inc
where exists
(select 1 from tbl_Comments com
  where inc.incidentId = com.incidentID
    and CommentFromUser = <<<input user_name>>>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?  (I'm assuming the comments table has an `IncidentID` column to join on, although you didn't specify it.)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_incidents
  WHERE IncidentID IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT IncidentID
       FROM tbl_comments
       WHERE CommentFromUser = 'Casualbob'
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use your `GROUP BY` like you thought you should, but for your un-grouped fields you can do an aggregation like `MAX`.

The `MAX` and `MIN` for say `IncidentDate` for the same incident will obviously be the same, but applying the aggregate function to that field allows it to be returned without being grouped on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from both tables, which you appear to, you have to accept that the data from the parent table will be repeated. This is because the record is differnt if only one of the fields is different.  If you only want to show the data once in your interface, you can manipulate the way it is shown by the application but you should be returning exactly what you say you are returning right now.

Alternatively, you can group all the data from the chiled table into a comma delimted list. This is far more complex and usually not a very performant way to do business and it works very badly if you need to show more than one field from the child table.